# using agg (antigrain) library and getting gsl shell working

Tags: macos, graphics, lua, gsl

My main aim is to get the GSL Shell working on my OSX 10.7 system.  So far I have the correct version of lua with the correct patches running.  I also have a working version of GSL which compiles and runs example programs.  I can build agg perfectly and also run their example programs by running make in the macosx_sdl folder.

My first question is how on earth do I create my own project with agg?  I know that you are supposed to simply add the files to your project file and go, but this does not seem to want to compile for me.  Is it simply a case of adding the include directory and the libagg.a?

Finally, how do I build gsl shell?  Currently it complains about the agg-plot folder a lot, so where do I put the agg files to make this build, then when i've done it where do I place the agg files so that the lua scripts can get to them?!

Hope someone can help!

Comment: It seems that the antigrain library doesn't have any Lua scripts. Why is this question tagged "Lua"? What do you mean by "the lua scripts"?

Answer (score 1):

In general to use the AGG library you need to make sure that the compiler is able to find the headers files and, during the linking, the libraries, either in form of a static or dynamic libraries.

To make the headers files and the libraries available you need to take into account the system that is used to build the software. If a traditional makefile sistem is used you need to add some flags to make sure that the headers file can be found. This can be achieved by adding into the makefile something like:

CFLAGS += -I/path/to/agg/headers

and for the linker:

LIBS += -L/path/to/agg/library -lagg -lm

In the specific case of GSL Shell 1.1 the file "make-packages" is used in the Makefile to configure the required packages. You can add here the flags required to locate the AGG library:

AGG_INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/agg2
AGG_LIBS = -lagg -lX11 -lpthread -lsupc++

you should just modify the path provided with the "-I" option and, in AGG_LIBS, add an option "-L/path/to/agg/library" to specify the path where the AGG libraries are located.

Please note also that the agg libraries depends on other libraries. For example on linux it needs at least the X11 library. The libraries supc++ may be needed if the linking is made by invoking gcc instead of g++ because if gcc is used the C++ runtime libraries are not included.